# Application of Parseval's identity to a vectorial series

Tags: hilbert-spaces, parsevals-identity

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{e_n, n\in \mathbb N\}$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$.
Determine whether these series converge in $H$:

1. $\sum \frac{e_n}{n}$
2. $\sum\frac{e_n}{\sqrt{n}}$

The Parseval's identity tells us  that for every $x \in H$,
$$
\displaystyle \sum _m|\langle x,e_m\rangle |^2=\|x\|^2.
$$
Let $x=\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{e_n}{n}$, then $|\langle x,e_m\rangle|^2=\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}\quad \forall m \in \mathbb N$. Which is a convergent Riemann series. In other hand we have
$$
\|x\|^2= \displaystyle\sum_n |\langle \frac{e_n}{n}, \frac{e_n}{n}\rangle|^2=\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}
$$

and there I got confused.

Is there a merciful soul that can help me?
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

$\sum a_ne_n$ converges if and only if $\sum|a_n|^{2} <\infty$. Hence the first series is convergent and the second one is not.

Proof: Recall that Hilbert spaces are complete so a series in $H$ converges if and only if the partial sums form a  Cauchy sequence. $\|\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} a_ne_n\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}|a_n|^{2}$ and a series $\sum b_n$ of non-negative numbers converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} b_k \to 0$ as $ m>n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please, which argument did you use to conclude that  $\sum a_n e_n$ converges if and only if $\sum|a_n|^{2} <\infty$.

Comment: @Furdzik Did you read the proof I gave for this statement. Which step in the proof you have difficulty with?

Comment: It's crystal clear. Thank toi.